# Hyperlinks with JavaScript disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Assume that I have some hyperlinks on a website. If you click on a link, something is going:

```
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div').toggle()
})
```

**On a mobile phone**, if user have JavaScript disabled, nothing will happen.

Here comes CSS:

```
a + div {
  display: none;
}

a:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

But hovers don't work on mobile devices!?

How can I deal with that to allow smartphone/tablet users click on such a link with JS disabled?

Comment: Who's concerned about devices with JS disabled? Just too bad for them...

Comment: Tell those people to enable JS... I don't know many people that browse with JS disabled, but if I did, I'd tell them to stop being silly

Comment: I'm not even sure I know how to turn JavaScript off on Android Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

<del>A common way to do this is through the checkbox hack. In stead of an a + div combination you could do a label + input type="checkbox" + div combination.
With some simple CSS you can then hide the actual checkbox but still use the label to change the :checked state of the hidden checkbox and use a :checked + div rule to show or hide the div.</del>

CBroe pointed out :target is better in this case then the checkbox hack. It basically allows you change the CSS according to the hash of the current url of the page.

Something like this should work:

```
<a href="#myContent1">Link text</a>
<div id="myContent1">I only show up if you click the link.</div>

a + div {
  display: none;
}

a + div:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I’d rather suggest using `:target` in such a case.

Comment: Hmm, I was unfamiliar with the :target solution, but googled it and it seems like a better fit for this case, yes. Thanks for pointing it out.